# Can I use subscribe to Topic instead of maintaining tokens without performance lag

Tags: android, performance, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm maintaining tokens for sending notifications to a user. It also needs to implement multiple device if logged on with the same userId. So maintaining it is giving me issue as well as increase my db.
For this can I use subscribeToTopic(UserId) and then send it using that and unsubscribe on logout. 
I dont want instant notification. Is there any maximum number of count I can subscribe to and if subscribeToTopic count increase upto 50,000 will it affect anything?

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented maximum number of subscribers to a topic, so you can definitely subscribe 50.000 without problems.

Whether there is a performance difference between using topics and doing the so-called fan-out yourself is impossible for us to say. When using topics the fan-out to the device IDs is done on Google's shared infrastructure, and you have no control over its performance. When you do the fan-out to device IDs yourself, you have control over the performance.